# Choose 4 types of soup from 10 varieties, with constraint?

Tags: combinatorics

We have to choose 4 types of soup from a supermarket's 10 varieties, such that at least 2 are identical. In how many ways can we do this ?

We have 10 varieties of soup like so {v1, .. v10}. We can partition our choices into those with 4 identical (e.g. {v1, v1, v1, v1}), those with 3 identical (e.g. {v1, v1, v1, v2}), and those with 2 identical (e.g. {v1, v1, v2, v3}). Our total number of choices is then:

10 + 10.9 + 10.9C2 = 10 + 90 + 360 = 460

The textbook answer is 505. Can anyone point out my error ?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a case!

Here's a hint: you're 45 below the right answer, 45 = 10C2. What choice can you make that requires you to pick two varieties where the order is not important?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I missed the cases like {v1, v1, v2, v2} with 10C2 possibilities. I'm not sure combinatorics tests mathematical ability as much as pattern recognition. (Good hint, BTW, but why, oh, why does this forum accept comments on hitting return)

Comment: @ukmaths: a number of us have complained about comments being posted when you hit return.  The site operators claim others like it, so it won't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

One could alternatively find the total number of sub-multisets of size $4$, namely $$\left(\binom{10}{4}\right)=\binom{10+4-1}{4}=715$$ (the first function is the multichoose function; refs: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)) and subtract the number of sub-multisets of size $4$ with no duplicates, namely $$\binom{10}{4}=210$$ which gives $$505.$$